# What data type should be set in registerOutParameter() when returning record

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I created following procedure in GP 4.3.7.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.mytest(param varchar)
RETURNS SETOF record
LANGUAGE sql
AS
$body$
SELECT * from test.mytable;
$body$
VOLATILE;
```

What datatype should I set when register output param in following java code:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call test.mytest(?, ?)}");
cstmt.setString(1, "abc");
cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
cstmt.execute();
```

I tried many data types as the param in registerOutParameter(). However, I always received the exception:

> A CallableStatement was executed with an invalid number of parameters

Is there anyone can give me some advice?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Do you think Functions can return more than one value or more than one row? Moreover, you have declared Function with one parameter `param`, but you are calling with two parameters. And finally you cannot call a Function with keyword `Call`. Are you referring to Stored Procedure

Answer (score 2):

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/callproc.html#callproc-resultset-setof

"Functions that return data as a set should not be called via the CallableStatement interface, but instead should use the normal Statement or PreparedStatement interfaces."

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from test.mytest(1, 'abc')");
while (rs.next()) 
{
    //do something here
}
rs.close();
stmt.close();
```